# What is the best SQL type to use for a large string variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Apologies for the rather basic question.

I have an error string that is built dynamically. The data in the string is passed by various third parties so I don't have any control, nor do I know the ultimate size of the string.

I have a transaction table that currently logs details and I want to include the string so that I can reference back to it if necessary.

2 questions:

- How should I store it in the database?
- Should I do anything else such as contrain the string in code?

I'm using Sql Server 2008 Web.

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939(v=sql.100).aspx, if its bigger than that you are logging too much error information.

Comment: @Jodrell - thats the thing - I don't know. Theoretically the third party could send an error message for every invalid input field I send them 35 * 100-150 chars

Comment: @dotnetnoob - So worst case would be 5,250 characters. Unicode or "plain vanilla"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store non unicode text, you can use:

```
varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)
```

Maximum length is 2GB.

Other alternatives are:

```
binary or varbinary
```

Drawbacks: you can't search into these fields and index and order them 
and the maximum size : 2GB.

There are TEXT and NTEXT, but they will be deprecated in the future, 
so I don't suggest to use them.
They have the same drawbacks as binary.

So the best choice is one of varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).

Comment: `[n]varchar(max)` is 2GB not 4,000/8,000 characters. So supports 1 or 2 billion characters dependent on single or double byte. There is no need to store as binary.

Comment: DV removed  but you've still left in the bit about "If you want to store larger strings use bynary or varbynary". This is not correct except if using `varbinary(max)` in conjunction with filestream. `varbinary(max)` in the DB has the same 2GB limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) too.

Comment: When you say "Check this out" are you suggesting the use of `ntext` or drawing attention to the warning?

Comment: Yes actually thats what I wanted as you have already pointed the official link in the comments so I thought to go with this one ;)

Comment: I am just trying to draw the attention to the warning!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Eventualy, you can enable and use a FILESTREAM feature of SQL Server 2008 (it's supported by WEB edition), and deal with extra large amount of data in sense of documents.

Of course, you need to be sure that you will use a benefit of this service.